# PHPMailer - Uploading a file

Tags: attachments, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send applications for jobs and can send over all the data except for the file e.g. word doc, PDF's.

The process is;

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" class="uploaded_file">
```

Which then goes to a jQuery file;

```
var uploaded_file $form.find('.uploaded_file').val();
```

Then it goes to PHP file to send;

```
$mail->addAttachment($uploaded_file);
```

However when the email arrives, there is no attachment!

I think the issue is in the jQuery but not finding much to prove my theory...

Can anyone assist?

Cheers

Comment: have you verified that $uploaded_file is not empty ?

Comment: I try `console.log(uploaded_file);` but nothing happens and my gulp file crashes, so suggests the jQuery is wrong but not sure why. I wonder if it's because I'm asking it to locate `.val()` yet it's an file not a value?

Comment: Noticed `var uploaded_file $form.find('.uploaded_file').val();` missed an = sign so added that and now get C:\fakepath\CV.docx but the file still doesn't attach to the email.